# How do you compile a c program in atom editor

Tags: c, gcc, atom-editor

I downloaded atom a couple of days ago and I can't seem to find the right package or where and how you compile the program.
does anyone know?

Comment: atom is an xml file format. there is no "program" for atom, there's just programs which can read atom's xml and display it. If you mean atom-editor, then you've mis-tagged this question.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: look at the question tags. "atom" != "atom-editor".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atom is "simply" a Text editor that is not able to compile anything. If you use a Makefile, then there are a few add-ons for building targets via key bindings.

If not, open a terminal and use the C compiler on your system. On Linux/Unix machines you probably want to use gcc:

```
gcc <your_source>.c -o <output_name>
```

### EDIT

Or take a look at [This Package](https://atom.io/packages/gpp-compiler)

Answer (score 4):

Now, it's possible to run and compile (also debug) **C** and **C++** program from within atom editor.
Install [gpp compiler](https://atom.io/packages/gpp-compiler) package in atom editor.

---

***Prerequisites:***
***Windows:***
You'll need to install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) and add it to your [system PATH](http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/).

***Mac:***
You'll need to install [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/).

***Linux:***
The GNU Compiler Collection may come with your distribution. Run `which gcc g++` to find out.

---

> To compile and run: `F5`
>
> To debug: `F6`

Comment: I get a "chrome-like inspect element" window when I press F5. I checked keybindings, it's properly set to `gpp-compiler:compile`. Any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: Compared to other editors and IDEs (e.g. Emacs, Geany), this package seems to be rather "bare". I only get a popup with gcc's error message, but then I have to manually go to the corresponding error line etc. There is no highlighting of errors, nor a way to click and go to the error etc, so essentially it seems to be very similar to just switching to a terminal and running gcc?

Comment: Is this atom package also useful for debugging C programmes?

Answer (score 1):

here's a link for atom gnu gcc compiler-- https://atom.io/packages/gpp-compiler
1. download it
2. place the file in atom's package folder
3. press F5 on atom editor to RUN n Compile your file.

it will open text.ext as a output.